# New assets field not showing up for some users

Tags: assets, field, cache

I've added an assets field to an existing channel that shows up fine for me on both the new entry and editing existing entries, but it's not showing up for some users. I've cleared cache in Craft Utilities, had users log out/in after clearing their browser cache but no luck.

Is there some other cache or setting that would cause this? I'm relatively new to Craft so I may be missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

It was a User permissions problem. I didn't realize each folder has its own permissions per user group.